# utorrent - move all files from subdirectories (downloaded torrents) to parent

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

Whenever I download torrents, sometimes they have subfolders within the torrent - for example sometimes the file is stored within a folder in the torrent. uTorrent recreates this folder as it is downloading.

Is there a way I can automatically have that folder and all sub folders removed, and have all the files in the one parent directory?

Similar to when you extra a zip file but you untick "create original directory structure"

I'm using Win 7 and uTorrent 3.0.

Thanks.

Comment: http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=136970 This URL leads to the uTorrent forums where someone has asked for this exact same feature. I suggest you lend a comment there so it gets noticed even more. I agree; This feature needs to be there for proper auto-downloading of series' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Suction](http://www.geek-republic.com/software/suction/) + uTorrent settings. Please note basically suction already does what you need but you can tweak even more.
It's a good idea to use a batch for starting suction, cheking if the target folder exists and other stuff.

[image: example]

Comment: It looks like there is no way to set it per-torrent; it runs for every torrent, and Suction seems to pull every file. That’s good for some torrents, but be careful because it can destroy others. Also, it requires version 2.2+.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the locations of files in the torrent before starting it to wherever you want.

[image]

An easier method would be to set the location of the torrent as a whole **before** you begin downloading it. Once µTorrent starts downloading, it creates the folder and files, but if you change the location before downloading anything, µTorrent will create the files at the specified location, ignoring the directory was specified in the `.torrent` file.

Note that you will need to do this *twice* if using a magnet link because the file and folder information is not stored in the magnet and will be retrieved once you have begun the download, however leaving the download active will create the folder when it transfers, so you must:

1. Start the magnet download
2. As soon as it retrieves the metadata, **stop it**

   - This is made easier if you temporarily set your download speed to the minimum (1KBps) before starting to reduce the likelihood of transferring any data
3. Set the location
4. Start the torrent again

It sounds like a lot of work, but it’s pretty quick and easy when you’ve done it once, and allows you to dump save the contents of a torrent to a given location per-torrent, without losing the directory structure.

[image]

Comment: A good point, but a hassle to do for every torrent. +1 for the effort though!